# Understanding how jQuery works

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery. I'm taking a course and was given a test project, but I have no idea what to do. I'm just asking for someone to help me with an understanding. Here are the requirements:

[image: Assignment]

Here is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// site code
for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
{   
    //jQuery factory
    $("body").appendTo("<a href=">"+i+</>")
}
});
```

Here is the HTML section:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <ul id="navleft"></ul>
    <ul id="navright"></ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't want answers, but a push in the right direction. I need a tutor, but they are so expensive and my teacher is never to be found, so I'm seeing if someone wouldn't mind helping.

Comment: The syntax highlighting stackoverflow shows for your code should be a big hint for part of the problem...

Comment: That's a bit too much info @Kevin-B.

Comment: Use a JavaScript debugger that displays errors. Firebug for Firefox or the inbuilt inspector on all webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari).

Comment: Not to be mean or anything but homework or similar is kind of considered not to be a good thing to post just so you know.

If you are more specific however it is ok to post it.

Comment: I also found learning jQuery difficult, however, gaining a real understanding of the DOM model is key. That makes a massive difference despite what others may say. http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/

Comment: @ jgillich:I now have Firebug, and it is really helpful.

Comment: @ Pablo: I would have done it better, but I have no idea what I'm doing here, so being more specific couldn't be done since I don't know what to say, but show by what I have. Sorry though. @ Sean: I don't see any syntax highlight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have both logical and syntax errors. Make sure your statements end with a '`;`'

I think you are confused of how the `$()` works. In simple terms, you can put in the `$()` whatever you want to select from the page. So you are doing `$('body')`, which tells jquery, "hey give me back all of the elements that are tagged `<body>`", which is of course just the one.

Your assignment wants you to 'appendTo' the 'navleft' id. So what would you want to select from the page? Please note that to lookup an Id using `$()` you should do `$("#id")`

now for appendTo, you assignment says to append a `<li>`, however you are appending something else.

You should append EXACTLY what it says to append.  `<li><a>..<a/><li/>`

The last traversing requirement you should have enough to do yourself. Just remember that $() will select all items that you tell it to, so what do you need to select to apply a color to all the anchors?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the obvious syntax errors in your post, I would look at the documentation for [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo) and [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append).

<sup>... and then swap round `"body"` and `"<a href=">"+i+</>"`</sup>

---

You can track down syntax errors and runtime exceptions by using the Web Tools bundled with your browser. In most browsers (Chrome, FireFox) access these via F12 on your keyboard.

Comment: I forgot about the document at the jQuery site. Thanks